POCO and Kerberos authentication
I am using POCO to send http requests to a server with HTTPClientSession class. Requests must go through a proxy (ok with HTTPClientSession->setProxyConfig). When the proxy requires NTLM authentication, it works with the authentication method "Poco::Net::HTTPClientSession::ProxyAuthentication::PROXY_AUTH_NTLM". But when the proxy requires KERBEROS authentication, there is no authentication method. Do you know if it is possible, with POCO, to send http requests through a proxy that requires Kerberos authentication?
I try to send http requests through a proxy that requires Kerberos authentication. Is it possible? Do you know how?

It does not seem to be possible.
For Windows specifically, Poco has 90% of the necessary SSPI code in SSPINTLMProvider.cpp which could potentially be copy-pasted to create a Kerberos provider (mostly replacing "NTLM" with "Negotiate" to have it call SPNEGO).
For other platforms it would need to be reimplemented using GSSAPI (which is similar in concept to SSPI but not API-compatible).
